# PHP Infection all mutants were not covered by tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mutation-testing, infection

I'm trying to implement the [infection/infection](https://github.com/infection/infection) php mutation testing library into a new project of mine. I've set up some tests which all pass, then ran infection.

Infection returns the following:

```
You are running Infection with xdebug enabled.
    ____      ____          __  _
   /  _/___  / __/__  _____/ /_(_)___  ____ 
   / // __ \/ /_/ _ \/ ___/ __/ / __ \/ __ \
 _/ // / / / __/  __/ /__/ /_/ / /_/ / / / /
/___/_/ /_/_/  \___/\___/\__/_/\____/_/ /_/

Running initial test suite...

PHPUnit version: 7.4.0

   23 [============================] < 1 sec

Generate mutants...

Processing source code files: 3/3
Creating mutated files and processes: 14/14
.: killed, M: escaped, S: uncovered, E: fatal error, T: timed out

SSSSSSSSSSSSSS                                       (14 / 14)

14 mutations were generated:
       0 mutants were killed
      14 mutants were not covered by tests
       0 covered mutants were not detected
       0 errors were encountered
       0 time outs were encountered

Metrics:
         Mutation Score Indicator (MSI): 0%
         Mutation Code Coverage: 0%
         Covered Code MSI: 0%

Please note that some mutants will inevitably be harmless (i.e. false positives).

Time: 1s. Memory: 10.00MB
```

When I dug a little deeper into my [infection-log.txt](https://pastebin.com/WUHTPdUS), I found that many of the uncovered mutants were for the [Function Signature Visibility mutator](https://infection.github.io/guide/mutators.html#Function-Signature).

The issue I am running into is that my tests do cover those methods. I manually changed some of my methods from public to protected, re-ran my phpunit tests and the tests failed. I'm really not sure where to proceed from here. I have a hunch that infection isn't properly detecting my phpunit test suite, but I cannot find any discussion about this being an issue elsewhere.

If anyone has any ideas let me know.

Comment: Is there a log file, or a more verbose mode to show you all the tests which passed after mutations?

Comment: @FrankerZ Only the infection-log.txt which I linked to. I did tell infection to generate the other log files in-case, but none of them provide me with any additional information. PHPUnit's --verbose mode also doesn't really seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was on me! Running around in circles for hours only to find out it was your own fault is a real pain.

I had the set the phpunit configuration option `forceCoversAnnotation` which makes it so that

> "Code Coverage will only be recorded for tests that use the @Covers
>   annotation documented in @Covers."

At no point was I using `@Covers` annotations, nor do I think I would normally. I apologise for the confusing issue, thanks!